# healing stillness

Tags: translation

How would I translate the phrase 'healing stillness'?

The sense I mean here is that the stillness has the quality of healing, that the healing is spiritual (beyond ordinary physical healing) and the stillness is that of meditative silence.

謝謝

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest “靜以養生”

roughly,

“靜” - “still, quiet, peaceful”

“以“ - “therefore, in order to”

“養生” - “looking after one’s health”

have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

There is something called a 康复花园, a healing garden

Just put that in Baidu to see the pretty pictures.

康复 means recover, recuperate, heal

平静 can translate stillness

From here:
寻找难得的内心平静
Seek that hard to find inner stillness

and here:
这会帮助你回到平静放松的状态，加快康复速度。
This will help you return to a quiet, relaxed state and heal faster.

I first thought of：康复的平静

But apparently, that is not good Chinese. Sounds strange.

静养疗养院
a sanatorium for recovering from illness

静养：recuperate

这个地方有一种能让人静养的功（疗）效。
This place has a kind of recuperative effect.

恢复的安静 (sounds weird I'm told)
healing stillness

安静地恢复
quietly recover

静养
quietly recover

Whereby:

静 = 安静：quiet, peaceful
养 = 休养：recuperate, recover, convalesce

So I think, Chinese prefers 'heal in stillness' over 'a healing stillness'